# i don't understand ndarray memory

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy-ndarray

```
from ctypes import string_at
from sys import getsizeof
from binascii import hexlify


secret = np.array([0xabababab, 0xbcbcbcbc, 0xcdcdcdcd])

print("secret : ", hex(id(secret)))
print(hexlify(string_at(id(secret), getsizeof(secret))))

print("secret.data : ", secret.data, hex(id(secret.data)))
print(hexlify(string_at(id(secret.data), getsizeof(secret.data))))


print("data[0] : ", secret[0], hex(id(secret[0])))
print(hexlify(string_at(id(secret[0]), getsizeof(secret[0]))))

print("data[1] : ", secret[1], hex(id(secret[1])))
print(hexlify(string_at(id(secret[1]), getsizeof(secret[1]))))

print("data[2] : ", secret[2], hex(id(secret[2])))
print(hexlify(string_at(id(secret[2]), getsizeof(secret[2]))))
```

I am analyzing the memory of numpy's ndarray.

While checking the memory address, I noticed an incomprehensible output.

We saw that the memory addresses of secret[0], secret[1], and secret[2] are all the same, but the stored values are different.

How is this possible?

Isn't the id() function just returning a memory address?

I will wait for the answers from the masters. Thank you.

ps: If you have any books or resources that deal with Python's memory structure, please recommend it. :)

```
secret :  0x7f8e61d6b990
b'0100000000000000201ff95f8e7f00009058d000000000000100000000000000608805010000000068880501000000000000000000000000a037f95f8e7f00000705000000000000000000000000000001000000000000004084a300000000001d0000000000000013e3adb2fffc9b90e4686f6d652f6861'
secret.data :  <memory at 0x7f8e5cd89708> 0x7f8e5a17c348
b'0000000000000000a09ca3000000000003000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffff070000006e6f206100000000000000009058d0000000000090b9d6618e7f0000180000000000000008000000000000000000000001000000f0341c01000000009897d85c8e7f0000a097d85c8e7f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000800000000000000000053000000530002000000000000004084a300000000008d00000000000000'
data[0] :  2880154539 0x7f8e5a332240   //same address!
b'4022335a8e7f0000a08cfa5f8e7f0000abababab000000005822335a8e7f0000'  //0xababab
data[1] :  3166485692 0x7f8e5a332240  //same address!
b'4022335a8e7f0000a08cfa5f8e7f0000bcbcbcbc000000005822335a8e7f0000' //0xbcbcbc
data[2] :  3452816845 0x7f8e5a332240 //same address!
b'4022335a8e7f0000a08cfa5f8e7f0000cdcdcdcd000000005822335a8e7f0000' //0xcdcdcd
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW0HO.png)

Comment: For starters, `id` provides **a unique id for the object**. In CPython, this *happens* to be the address of the PyObject header. `numpy.ndarray` objects are essentially object-oriented wrappers around primitive C-like arrays. When you retrieve a value from a `numpy.ndarray`, e.g. `secret[0]` it *create a new object* to represent that primitive value. They happen to have the same `id` because `id` only guarantees a unique number for the *lifetime of the object*, and here, the runtime is reusing the id since the objects that are created are immediately reclaimed because they are never referenced

Comment: Thanks to you, I can understand. But now I want to check the array address where the value is stored. Is there any way to check?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want that address? What do you plan to do with it? Are you trying to interact with a  shared C/C++ library? There's not much useful you can do with a memory address in Python... Anyway, this is available at `secret.ctypes.data`

Comment: I am experimenting with cache side channel attack in Python. As you say, memory addresses are not useful in Python, but they are used as important information in cache side channel attacks. Thank you for answer. Please take care of your health. :)